# "two-phase commits [...] always cause problems in the long run" - why?

Tags: transactions, cqrs

In the [CQRS Journey, Chapter 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591563.aspx) there is an imaginary dialog called *Pushing changes from the Conference Management bounded context* between two developers. They are discussing the transaction options in a CQRS architecture to have saving and publishing events bound together. In the 4th paragraph from the end, developer 2 says:

> "Second, we're trying to avoid two-phase commits because they always cause problems in the long run."

I was wondering why this is.

Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice explanation is given in [Your coffee-shop does not use 2PC](http://eaipatterns.com/docs/IEEE_Software_Design_2PC.pdf): Baically it comes down to bad scalability due to waiting when synchronizing.